# NSMutableArray does not hold added items after for loop

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, nsmutablearray, persistent

I try to make an Facebook Graph call and add some items to an array. The items are added in a for loop and the array looks fine. But after the for loop the items are vanished.

I using xcode 4.5 with Facebook SDK 3.1.

What did I miss?

### TableViewController.m

```c
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController ()
@end

@implementation TableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *recipes;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    recipes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", nil];
    [recipes addObject:@"foobar"];
    NSLog(@"recipes before FBRquestConnection: %@", recipes);

    [FBRequestConnection
     startWithGraphPath:@"search?type=place&center=37.785834,-122.406417"
     completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                         id result,
                         NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             for (id item in [result objectForKey:@"data"]) {
                [recipes addObject:[item objectForKey:@"name"]];
             }
         NSLog(@"recipes after for-loop: %@", recipes);
         NSLog(@"amount of recipes after for-loop: %u", [recipes count]);
         }
     }];
    NSLog(@"amount of recipes after FBRequestConnection: %u", [recipes count]);
}
```

### Debug Console Output

```
2012-12-27 23:09:44.056 barbar[3481:19a03] recipes before FBRquestConnection: (
    "Egg Benedict",
    foobar
)
2012-12-27 23:09:44.056 barbar[3481:19a03] amount of recipes after FBRequestConnection: 2
2012-12-27 23:09:44.516 barbar[3481:19a03] recipes after for-loop: (
    "Egg Benedict",
    foobar,
    "Union Square, San Francisco",
    "Benefit Cosmetics",
    "San Francisco | The Official Guide",
    "BareMinerals by Bare Escentuals",
    "Viator.com",
    "Bleacher Report",
    "Downtown San Francisco",
    "AMC Metreon 16",
    "Cheesecake Factory",
    SquareTrade,
    "Westfield San Francisco Centre",
    "Bloomingdale's San Francisco",
    "Macy's San Francisco Union Square",
    Xoom,
    "Parc 55 Hotel",
    "Pottery Barn",
    "AT&T Park",
    Bebo,
    Snapfish,
    "Hilton San Francisco Union Square",
    uTorrent,
    "The Westin St. Francis",
    TRUSTe,
    "Apple Retail Store - San Francisco"
)
2012-12-27 23:09:44.516 barbar[3481:19a03] amount of recipes after for-loop: 26
```

cheers -- jerik

Comment: what is the problem here, this looks fine to me. you are performing an asynchronous operation so maybe the order in which the logs happen is confusing?

Comment: The code is working perfectly. The log shows all the objects after the for-loop. Why don't you think this is working? Keep in mind that the log statement outside (after) the connection block is called before the for-loop actually executes. This is because the connection block is done on a background thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your items are added in the completion block of the graph call.

When you do an Api call it goes to the server and does not fire the completion block until the web request has returned with your results.

Therefore when your last line hits, the api call is still being requested and has yet to return.

Comment: Ok. This explains the wired order in of the debug output. My problem is, that in the the Iphone-Simulator only to items are shown in the table view.

So somehow I have to wait until the Request is finished and then the tableview should be loaded... but how do I do this?

Comment: [tableView reloadData] is the simplest way. however there are other commands that will let you insert new items and fade them in rather than reload the table view from scratch. I would look into those. but for now the reloadData command will get you off and running.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the `__block` on the declaration (I had some problems once with this), if you want to make it mutable within the block object. Right now the scope is suppressed only inside the block.

Also take a look at this link for more information about the scope of variables inside blocks.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html

Answer (score 0):

Your completion block is being fired on a random thread. The idea behind blocks is set-it-and-forget-it. By this, I mean that you're not guaranteed to know when that completion block is going to fire. It could be 2 seconds after, it could 2 minutes.

To illustrate this, set two breakpoints: One at the top of your viewDidLoad method and another inside the completion block and start stepping through the code. You'll see that the breakpoint outside of the block gets hit. As you step through and get to your completion block, you don't move inside of the block. Instead, you step right over it and onto your last `NSLog` statement, which is why you think you only get the original 2 objects. Resume execution of your program and the breakpoint inside the block will get fired.

This should help show that completion blocks are triggered at some indeterminate time afterwards and that your array is actually just fine.